# How to use SharedPreferences in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to save my String information with sharefPreferences in file as a key-value

Comment: Search in google, lot's example are available for shared preference.

Comment: Use this link for the solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/11027631/2675669

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Comment: You may follow this simple [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html):

Answer (score 1):

To obtain shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
  "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To read preferences:

```
String dateTimeKey = "com.example.app.datetime";

// use a default value using new Date()
long l = prefs.getLong(dateTimeKey, new Date().getTime());
```

To edit and save preferences:

```
Date dt = getSomeDate();
prefs.edit().putLong(dateTimeKey, dt.getTime()).commit();
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values